# Oxyplot minimum autoscale range

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am using oxyplot to create line series charts in my c# application.

The data is loaded in real time as a test progresses.

I am currently using `LinearAxis.MinimumRange` to prevent auto scaling to zoom right into the data to prevent the screen being filled with noise at the start of the test before values start changing.

However, by design this property limits how far the user is able to zoom in, is there a simple way beyond hooking into the scale changed events to achieve the functionality I want which is, to put it more simply, a default plot size that when exceeded autoscaling kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this ended up being wrap adding points into my own function (I am directly manipulating LineSeries.Points).

Now I just set min and max when setting up my axes and then when adding a point, check if it is outside these limits, if they are set the limits to NaN so autoscale resumes.